# iterm2: how to use just one pane but multiple columns?

Tags: multiple-columns, iterm2, pane

it's easy to split panes in iterm2, but that will create multiple prompts/sessions, one for each pane.

What i need is to use just one pane and keep one prompt, but there could be multiple columns, so when there are lots of text (narrow in width, but long vertically), words can move to left columns instead moving out of the screen. This way I can fully utilize the whole monitor when texts are narrow but long, and the terminal prompt is always at the bottom of right most column.

conceptually, it's kinda like MS Word multple column format. does anyone have an idea? thanks a lot!

Comment: There are terminals such as`tcvt` (http://subdivi.de/~helmut/tcvt/) but is not macOS aware, but would run via X11...

Comment: thanks a lot! can iterm2 or some mac terminal do similar things?

Comment: Not that I have seen personally....

Comment: is it possible to open 2 iterm2, and use one to redirect output to the other, with some kind of "offset", so two terminals can show consecutive contents